# How passing a protocol as parameter in Swift

Tags: protocols, swift

In Objective-C, I know how passing a `protocol` as parameter:

```
- (void)MyMethod:(Protocol *)myparameter
```

But in Swift there is no more `Protocol` type.

How can I pass a protocol as parameter without knowing which is ?

Comment: Passing a protocol, or passing an object that complies to one?

Comment: There is a `Protocol` type, see the Swift definition of NSObjectProtocol, it has the following function:

    `func conformsToProtocol(aProtocol: Protocol!) -> Bool`

And you can define your own method in the same way. But I'm still trying to figure out how to pass something into this method!

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'm still trying to understand how can I call `conformsToProtocol` method !

Comment: Pure swift implementation in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34995198/5389500

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34995198/5389500
Also works with Classes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one of your comments you say:

"I want create a method which return an array of type of class which implements a desired protocol."

Have you tried something like the following:

```
//notice the use of @objc here
@objc protocol AlertProtocol
{
    func getMyName()->String
}

class Class1 : AlertProtocol
{
     let name = "Object 1"
     func getMyName() -> String
    {
        return name
    }
}

class Class2 : AlertProtocol
{
    let name = "Object 2"
    func getMyName() -> String
    {
        return name
    }
}

//borrowing from and refactoring siLo's answer
func classesConformingToProtocol(proto:Protocol) -> [AnyClass]
{
    let availableClasses : [AnyClass] = [ Class1.self, Class2.self ]

    var conformingClasses = Array<AnyClass>()

    for myClass : AnyClass in availableClasses
    {
        if myClass.conforms(to: proto)
        {
            conformingClasses.append(myClass)
        }
    }

    return conformingClasses
}
```

Then use the above structure like this:

```
let classes = classesConformingToProtocol(AlertProtocol.self)
```

The tricky part that does the work is the "@objc" that exposes the protocol to the objective c runtime and allows us to pass any "Protocol Type" as a parameter.

Probably at some point in the future we will be able to do this in a "pure" Swift way.

Comment: In Swift 3, `conformsToProtocol(Protocol)` was replaced to `conforms(to: AnyObject.Type)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I have tried:

```
@objc protocol Walker
{
    func walk()
}

@objc protocol Runner
{
    func run()
}

@objc class Zombie : Walker
{
    func walk () { println("Brains...") }
}

@objc class Survivor : Runner
{
    func run() { println("Aaaah, zombies!") }
}

func classesConformingToProtocol(proto:Protocol) -> AnyClass[]
{
    let availableClasses : AnyClass[] = [ Zombie.self, Survivor.self ]

    var conformingClasses = Array<AnyClass>()

    for myClass : AnyClass in availableClasses
    {
        if myClass.conformsToProtocol(proto)
        {
            conformingClasses.append(myClass)
        }
    }

    return conformingClasses
}

// This does not work
let walkers = classesConformingToProtocol(Walker.self)
let runners = classesConformingToProtocol(Runner.self)
```

I have been unable to convert Swift's `Metatype` information into a `Protocol` object.

Comment: I want create a method which return an array of type of class which implements a desired protocol.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how can I pass a protocol as parameter ?

Comment: A *specific* protocol, or *any* protocol type?

Comment: What are you meaning with any protocol type ? The idea is I would write a method which take as parameter a protocol and return an array with all the classes in my project which implements the protocol passed in parameter.

Comment: Ah, you would need to use the `AnyClass` arguments, which is the metadata type for `class` and `protocols`. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Ok, this is for the prototype of the method. But I still don't know how can I passing the protocol as parameter. Imagine I've a protocol named `MyProtocol` how can I pass `MyProtocol` as the parameter of my method ?

Comment: So actually, there is not method to get the protocol type of a protocol ? :/

Answer (score 2):

In swift 2.0, I use it like this before:

*`classA.conformsToProtocol(XXXProtocol.self as! Protocol)`*

It doesn't works fine...

Look the definition of `Protocol:`

```
// All methods of class Protocol are unavailable. 
// Use the functions in objc/runtime.h instead.

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public class Protocol {
}
```

All are unavailable...and I don't know which to use instead in objc/runtime.h

So I have to use this method:

```
if ClassA is protocol<XXXProtocol> {
    // do something
}
```

Currently, it works...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't allow use `@objc` (because yours protocols have property, for example), the only solution that I found is with closure. Then, you need use a closure to use a protocol and return a value.

```
protocol Proto { }
protocol Proto2 { }
class Foo: Proto { }
class Bar: Proto, Proto2 { }
class Baz: Proto2 { }
class Qux { }

func printConforms(classList: [AnyClass], protoCond: (AnyClass) -> Any?) {
    for i in classList {
        print(i, terminator: " -> ")
        if protoCond(i) != nil {
            print("is subscriber")
        } else {
            print("NOT IS subscriber")
        }
    }
}

let myClasses: [AnyClass] = [Foo.self, Bar.self, Baz.self, Qux.self]
printConforms(classList: myClasses, protoCond: { $0 as? Proto.Type })
```

More complete example: https://gist.github.com/brunomacabeusbr/eea343bb9119b96eed3393e41dcda0c9

**Edit**

Another better solution is using generics, for example:

```
protocol Proto { }
class Foo: Proto { }
class Bar: Proto { }
class Baz { }

func filter<T>(classes: [AnyClass], byConformanceTo: T.Type) -> [AnyClass] {
    return classes.filter { $0 is T }
}

filter(classes: [Foo.self, Bar.self, Baz.self], byConformanceTo: Proto.Type.self)
// return [Foo.self, Bar.self]
```

Answer (score -2):

Worked out a way today (Xcode 6.1):

Firstly, the protocol must be marked as @objc for any checking to work.
Then use an "if let" cast to check for conformance.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    var protocolValue: Int { get set }
}

if let conformingObject = someObject as? MyProtocol {
   // conformingObject is now someObject cast to MyProtocol
   conformingObject.protocolValue = 3
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly the purpose of my question. My question was how pass a protocol type to a method. Not to check if a var is conform to a protocol.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was really answering your comment up above where you said "Thanks Sam, I'm still trying to understand how can I call conformsToProtocol method !"