# Find by Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

How can I pass a protocol as a parameter in Swift?

In Objective-C I could do this:

```
id <CurrentUserContex> userContex = [ServiceLocator locate:@protocol(CurrentUserContex)];
```

Service locator:

```
+ (id)locate:(id)objectType
```

**Edit**

After Qbyte answer tried using:

```
ServiceLocator.locate(CurrentUserContex.self)
```

But I'm getting 'CurrentUserContex.Protocol' does not confirm to protocol 'AnyObject'

So I tried:

```
ServiceLocator.locate(CurrentUserContex.self as! AnyObject)
```

But then I get:

```
Could not cast value of type 'ApplicationName.CurrentUserContex.Protocol' (0x7fec15e52348) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x7fec15d3d4f8).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How passing a protocol as parameter in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041258/how-passing-a-protocol-as-parameter-in-swift)

Comment: Why do you want to pass a protocol (as Type itself)?

Comment: You may find useful this answer: [Service Locator pattern in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34406818/3541063) with working implementations (two kinds presented, one basic and one with lazy initialization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use this if `CurrentUserContex` is the name of the protocol itself:

```
ServiceLocator.locate(CurrentUserContex.self)
```

If `CurrentUserContex` is a variable which type is a protocol use:

```
ServiceLocator.locate(CurrentUserContex)
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i'm getting this error when trying to use your answer: "Could not cast value of type 'ApplicationName.CurrentUserContex.Protocol' (0x7fec15e52348) to 'Swift.AnyObject"  When trying this: ServiceLocator.locate(CurrentUserContex.self as! AnyObject)

Comment: What are the methods you are trying to use? I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: Where does `ServiceLocator` come from? (Type, Module, Framework)

Comment: Its a Wrapper I created for "Typhoon" Dependency injection framework. In Typhoon the name of the method is "componentForType()"

Comment: Ok so I finally used this, and just changed  service locator method to "+ (id)locate:(protocol *)protocolType ". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you have to pass a class (all classes conform to the `AnyObject` protocol). So `CurrentUserContex` has to be a class too and you can try it with `.self` or without (Unfortunately, I don't have enough reference to tell you exactly which to use).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ServiceLocator.locate(CurrentUserContex.self as Protocol)
```

or (in some versions with a bug `Protocol` isn't recognized as being `AnyObject` for some reason):

```
ServiceLocator.locate((CurrentUserContex.self as Protocol) as! AnyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Protocol as a method argument:

```
protocol Describable: class{ var text: String { get } }
class A: Describable { var text: String; init(_ text: String) { self.text = text } }
class B: A {}
class C {}


let a = A("I am a")
let b = B("I am b")
let c = C()

func ofType<T>(instance: Any?,_ type: T.Type) -> T? { /*<--we use the ? char so that it can also return a nil*/
    if (instance as? T != nil) { return instance as? T }
    return nil
}

Swift.print(ofType(a, A.self)!.text) // I am a
Swift.print(ofType(a, Describable.self)!.text) // I am a
Swift.print(ofType(b, B.self)!.text) // I am b
Swift.print(ofType(c, C.self)) // instance of c
```

Comment: That is cool, but can you constrain the <T> to only be of Protocol types?

Comment: Asserting type in swift and objc is a bit tricky. You could try some of the suggestions in the source link above. Maybe NSStringFromProtocol could come in handy. Let me know what you figure out as there is very little information about this topic on the internet.

Comment: I finally decided, that I could accept AnyObject. I wanted to accept class protocol only, so this is good enough. I was able to make it work for protocol only, but that was requiring the protocol to be @objc, which I don't want. I'm exploring the possibilities of Swift, not how to plug Objective-C run time into Swift code.

Comment: you can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787085/swift-protocol-as-generic-parameter to see what I'm trying to do.