# Swift Protocol as Generic Parameter

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Given this class:

```
class ServiceRegistry {

  var store = [String : AnyObject]()
  var allRegisteredType: [String] {
      return store.map { $0.0 }
  }

  func registerInstance<T>(instance:AnyObject, forType type: T.Type) {
    store[String(type)] = instance
  }

  func instanceForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return store[String(type)] as? T
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can enforce that `T` must be a Protocol, without using the @obj?

Comment: Try to add some comments in the code. So that its easier to read. Right now its elegant, but not very readable straight away. So your trying to make instances based on class type only? Similarly to a factory pattern?

Comment: @GitSyncApp, it's a class to remove singleton. Any class that would be defined as a singleton is instantiated and stored in this ServiceRegistry. Ideally based only on it's protocol type. That ServiceRegistry could be injected, or accessible globally, in which case it would be the only singleton like class of the application. But the main question is not about the class, but about the generic functions.

Comment: I understand that its about the generic functions. The reason i asked for context is that it may be solvable by another approach as it seems like this class is ported from another language. Swift doesn't handle Protocols and class type assertion as easy as other languages.  Ill fire up playground and see what i can find.

Comment: @GitSyncApp, Yes I wrote that class in an Objective-C project and wanted to add it to a Swift one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified version of my type assertion technique. I added the **"as? AnyClass"** assert so that the type can only be of protocol type. **There might be a more elegant** way of doing this but going through my notes and research about class assertion this is what I came up with.

```
import Foundation

protocol IDescribable:class{}
class A:IDescribable{}
class B:A{}

let a = A()
let b = B()

func ofType<T>(instance:Any?,_ type:T.Type) -> T?{/*<--we use the ? char so that it can also return a nil*/
    if(instance as? T != nil && type as? AnyClass == nil){return instance as? T}
    return nil
}

Swift.print(ofType(a,A.self))//nil
Swift.print(ofType(a,IDescribable.self))//A
Swift.print(ofType(b,B.self))//nil
```

Comment: for more ideas surrounding type assertion you can check out my libraries on this on github: https://github.com/eonist/swift-utils/tree/master/misc/class

Comment: I also have a class that can create class instances that conform to a protocol via a method. Think factory pattern. Its just a playground project but let me know if you need it and ill post it here.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but If I create a `struct C {}` will pass. But since my argument is of AnyObject that struct wouldn't be able to pass there. I would be interested in your factory.

Comment: See how the protocol extends class? protocol IDescribable:class{} This means that that protocol only supports class types. Also struct is not a class so then you need to assert if it is a struct some other way. I try to avoid using struct because I utilise subclassing a lot. And protocols become more use full when they are restricted to work on classes.

Comment: Here is the dynamic instance creation that also conforms to a protocol: https://gist.github.com/eonist/d4304919a736a9916181  its also in daily use in this project: https://github.com/eonist/swift-utils/blob/ffe0cc4cb0ef1840cc862448bc924945ac4d8724/misc/layout/utils/LayoutUtils.swift

Comment: you can try replacing the instance:Any? with instance:AnyObject? maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm accepting the answer because it is resolving my specific issue. But I which there would be a less fragile way to do this. Thanks again for your time and insights.

Comment: No problem. In time there will probably be a more elegant solution. Thumbs up.