# Swift passing method params Struct Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

,Swift 4 how can I pass `Decodable Struct` in method params and parse it in `JSONDecoder()`?
error:

> Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Decodable,
>   from: Data)'

```
struct JsonRespons: Codable {
    let uid: String
    let msisdn: String
    let APK: String
    let fname: String
    let lname: String
}

struct JsonResponsError: Decodable {
    let uid: String
    let error: String
}

extension UIView {

func phoneAuth(serverApi path:String, jsonStruct:Codable){
    let jsonUrlString = Globals.JOSN_API_URL + path
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        return

    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard err == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonStruct.self, from: data)
            self.handleJsonResult(resalt: result as AnyObject)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()
}


    func handleJsonResult(resalt:AnyObject){
        print(resalt)
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. It looks like you want to be able to pass in an instance of an *arbitrary* `Decodable` type and then decode some data into a new instance based on the dynamic type of the original instance. But why exactly do you want that? How are you planning on using `result` afterwards?

Comment: @Hamish have edited example code I am passing result as parameter in method

Comment: Replace              `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonStruct.self, from: data)` with               `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonRespons.self, from: data)`
Let me know it works

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes it works, I whant to pass Struct as parameter like `phoneAuth("https://MY_API", JsonRespons.self)`

Comment: @VakhtangiBeridze You should make that clear in your question then ;) You don't want a `Codable` parameter in that case, you want a generic placeholder `T : Decodable` and have a parameter of `T.Type`.

Comment: Please show that method  `phoneAuth` and as @Hamish Said update that method with Generic parameter it is easy for you. And please update your ques accordingly . if possible

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya  how can I update with generic can you show me example, I am new in Swift ((

Comment: @Hamish how to archive that can you show me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) to the inheritance list for Landmark triggers an automatic conformance that satisfies all of the protocol requirements from [Encodable and Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types):

You can Use `Codable`

```
struct Landmark: Codable {
    var name: String
    var foundingYear: Int

    // Landmark now supports the Codable methods init(from:) and encode(to:), 
    // even though they aren't written as part of its declaration.
}
```

Alternative solution is

```
func phoneAuth(serverApi path: String, Completion block: @escaping ((Data) -> ())) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, res, err) in

        if let d = data {
            block(d)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Call a Methods

```
phoneAuth(serverApi: "yourUrl") { (data) in

    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourDecodable.self, from: data)
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get compile error on `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonStruct.self, from: data)` **Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Codable, from: Data)'**

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162499/6822622, you pass protocol as a parameter that is not possible with out @Objc,

Comment: your solution worked for me, it is little bit complicated but it helped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass it as a parameter, you can achieve decoding like below

```
extension UIView {

func phoneAuth(serverApi path:String){
    let jsonUrlString = Globals.JOSN_API_URL + path
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        return

}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
    guard err == nil else {
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonRespons.self, from: data)
        self.handleJsonResult(resalt: result as AnyObject)

    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
    }

}.resume()
}
```