# Cannot convert value of type "AProtocol".Protocol to expected argument type Protocol

Tags: swift, macos, swift-protocols

I'm trying to build a protocol for a NSXPCInterface and I'm facing a weird issue.

I created a protocol :

```
public protocol AProtocol {

    //functions in here

}
```

and when I want to add it to the exportedInterface of NSXPCConnection,

```
let newConnection: NSXPCConnection
newConnection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: AProtocol.self)
```

I get this strange error :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'AProtocol.Protocol' to expected argument type 'Protocol'
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the reason but its working try this. Add `@objc` before `protocol`

```
 @objc public protocol AProtocol {

//functions in here

}
```

don't forget to initialise `NSXPCConnection`

**Edit**: found reason from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041258/how-passing-a-protocol-as-parameter-in-swift)

"@objc" that exposes the protocol to the objective c runtime and allows us to pass any "Protocol Type" as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

The protocol you pass to an instance of `NSXPCInterface` has to be an Objective-C protocol as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcinterface/1416353-protocol):

> protocol: The Objective-C protocol that this interface is based on.

So all you have to do is mark `AProtocol` with `@objc`

```
@objc public protocol AProtocol {
}
```